My old Logitech HD PRO C910 camera doesn't work in Ubuntu 24.04
I connected this webcam. I turned my computer on. I logged in. I opened the Camera app. And the camera isn't found.


Althought there in no detail in your question about your system info, i think this answer for a common problem may solve your problem:
[https://askubuntu.com/a/1515774/750003][1]
Please provide some details, for example does other apps like Cheese works?

Open the Terminal


CTRL + Alt + T



Update the package lists from the repositories


~ sudo apt update



Restart pipewire


~ systemctl --user restart pipewire



Run snapshot from terminal. The package name of this camera app is snapshot


~ snapshot


It should work from now on.
